# Change slide in carousel depending on URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently using JQ Carousel (http://5509.github.io/jq.carousel/) and I'm trying to figure out how to change the slide in the carousel after the load pages. For example, there are 3 slides. When I click on the 3rd slide and loads a page with a URL containing ".../room-3/...", the slide on the loaded page will show the 3rd slide instead of showing the initial slide.

I tried the script below but no success. Any help is appreciated!

Update: Below is the entire script that I use for the carousel. This appears on all the pages that has the carousel. That last portion of the script, I'm assuming, needs to be updated so it would work on the other pages.

```
<script src="/path/to/jq.carousel.js"></script> 
<script>
// Script that appears on all pages
(function() {
    var $carousel = $('#carousel_2').carousel({
        start: 1,
        indicator: true
        });
  var currSlide = 1;
  var totalSlides = $(".carousel_box").length - 4;
    $('#carousel_2_prev').on('click', function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        $carousel.carousel('prev');
    });

    $('#carousel_2_next').on('click', function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        $carousel.carousel('next');
    });
}());
// Script that appears only on the third page that has the third room
$(document).ready(function() {
        if(window.location.href.indexOf('/room-3/') >= 0) {
            var $carousel = $('#carousel_2').carousel({
                start: 3
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: How are you setting the slides in the first place? Why can't each page have a different starting point?

Comment: using `start:3` should work. Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: [this](https://jsfiddle.net/13n358du/) works fine.. :)

Comment: I updated the script above. I'm not sure if the sections "var $carousel ..." or "if(window.location.href.indexOf..." both need to be updated or just one of them.